# Issue overcome with device compatiblity in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make layout for compatible with all devices, and first I tried with `Hdpi`, `mdpi` attribute but it doesn't work because some of tabs are consider as an `mdpi` device and they are taking resources from `mdpi` folder and its UI being too poor.  Then I tried with small,medium large and extra large attributes but its doesn't work properly because of same problem mentioned with `hdpi`, `mdpi`.  finally I'm going with small width attributes which will use resource according to their minimum width like layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp. But now another issue overcome with it is that Nexus and Galaxy Grand and other devices with 480*800 are using resources of 320dp excluding tab of the 480*800 ratio. So if anybody have solution of this type of problem then please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using GridView if possible in your app, the columns automatically resize themselves and their children as per device.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the android best practices. Did you use `wrap_content` and `match_parent` efficiently. It'll solve most of your problems